# Disk quota exceeded Linux

Tags: linux, ubuntu

Before you say this is a duplicate, I have looked everywhere on StackOverflow/StackExchange/SuperUser and couldn't find the answer.

I didn't have this problem up until now. When ever I do any file based actions such as edit a file or delete a file I get these errors:

```
edquota -rm: Cannot create temporary file: Disk quota exceeded
mkdir abc: mkdir: cannot create directory ‘abc’: Disk quota exceeded
```

The disk is also not full:

```
Filesystem      Size  Used Avail Use% Mounted on
/dev/vzfs       100G   20G   81G  20% /
```

`quota -v` returns:

```
Disk quotas for user root (uid 0):
     Filesystem  blocks   quota   limit   grace   files   quota   limit   grace
      /dev/vzfs 1555176       0       0           65499       0       0
```

`quotaoff -f -a -v` returns:

```
quotaoff: quotactl on /dev/vzfs [/]: Invalid argument
quotaoff: quotactl on /dev/vzfs [/]: Invalid argument
```

This problem is with all users, including root.

I am running Ubuntu 13.10 (GNU/Linux 2.6.32-042stab092.3 i686).

Comment: Take a look: http://linux.die.net/man/1/quota

Comment: edquota: Cannot create temporary file: Disk quota exceeded; - temporary - ? is there any problem with a tmpfs mounted system that would be full/memory shortage ?

Comment: How many files are already there?

Comment: @fixer1234 couple hundred defiantly, why?

Comment: @philippelhardy I'm using a virtual server from strato. As far as I know, there isnt a tmpfs mounted system.

Comment: If it already contained 65,499 files, that would have explained the problem.  But, alas...

Comment: If this is a virtual server, it might not be a Linux problem (and particularly, not one that you can fix). Have you contacted your hosting provider and asked them about any applicable limits, just in case?

Comment: @MichaelKjörling No I haven't contacted them yet. But in the server control panel there was an option to disable disk quotas. It was enabled so I though that might have been the cause but it didn't change anything

Comment: I would definitely suggest that you contact your hosting provider. The evidence definitely points toward this being something out of the control of your OS instance, and if nothing else it's easy to rule out provider-imposed limits as the cause, allowing us to focus on the "inside" side of the VM (which we also have a fighting chance of telling you how to fix).

Comment: Ok Guys. I found the problem. I was running out of inodes (%100)